# How to set "outline" as the default option in the Evince dropdown menu?

Tags: pdf, default, evince

I have a long pdf book and have to frequently access chapters using the index after clicking the outline option in the Evince dropdown menu as shown below.

[image: Evince dropdown menu]

My problem is that every time I open the document, **Evince shows the thumbnails view by default.** Is there any way I can view the outline of the document by default when I open Evince?

### **Update: Does not work in the Evince 3.32.0 snap package**

I installed Evince 3.32.0 using `snap install evince` and was surprised to learn that the newer version despite providing "Save Current Settings as Default" option for saving other settings, always opens the thumbnail view by default and what is worse **it does not even keep the side pane open by default.**

So each time in order to open the outline view, I have to open the side pane first and then click on the Outline option in the bottom navigation bar as shown below

[image: Outline option in bottom navigation bar]

P.S. I prefer using the Document Viewer or Evince as my pdf viewer and do not need a workaround using an alternate software

Comment: Which version of Evince is that? Mine is 3.32.0 and doesn't even have a dropdown menu. However, it has Thumbnails, Annotations and Bookmarks views (probably also Outline for documents that have one) and reproducably opens in the view it was last closed in.

Comment: @Jos I tried Evince 3.32.0. It does not open outline view by default, check out my updated question.

Comment: It works in mine. Try this: install `dconf-editor`, run it and open `org.gnome.evince`. Anything special in there?

Comment: @Jos I could not find anything helpful there. Are you using an apt package?  I am using a snap version of Evince 3.32.0, could there be a difference in behaviour of the apt and the snap packages?

Comment: Yes, mine is an apt package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Evince 3.28.4**

[image: Save Current Settings as Default option]

Select "Save Current Settings as Default" option in File options as shown in the picture and viola! The outline view will be set as default.